# Excel - Rank date range with similar criteria

Tags: excel, ranking

What I have

Column A criteria range 1

Column B criteria range 2

Column C criteria range 3

Column D Date Range

What I Want:

Column E to return the ranking number (1,2,3,...) from oldest to newest of dates that appear in column D that have the same value in all three criteria columns.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a data table from A1:D6, array formula in E1:

```
=MATCH(D1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(($D$1:$D$6)/(($C$1:$C$6=$B$1:$B$6)*($B$1:$B$6=$A$1:$A$6))),ROW($D$1:INDIRECT("$D$"&3))),0)*((C1=B1)*(B1=A1))
```

You must input this formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, not just ENTER, or it will not work

This makes use of the AGGREGATE function, which was introduced in Excel 2010, so will not work in earlier versions

Dates in rows where there is not matching criteria in columns A B and C return an error - you can wrap the entire formula in IFERROR to return blank, if preferred:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(D1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(($D$1:$D$6)/(($C$1:$C$6=$B$1:$B$6)*($B$1:$B$6=$A$1:$A$6))),ROW($D$1:INDIRECT("$D$"&3))),0)*((C1=B1)*(B1=A1)),"")
```